# How to ensure the statement about 'a' does not become centered and moved from "For every"

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, mathtools

[image]

I wrote this in latex and the 'a' contained in (0.1) became centered and I need it to remain part of the sentence. Please help if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us your short compilable tex code you used to get the included image ...

Comment: Please show us your LaTeX code.

Comment: this is identical to the question asked a minute ago by another user https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472667/alignment-is-off  If you are the same person you can ask the staff exchange staff to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely used `\[a \in (0,1)\]`; here `\[`...`\]` puts its contents in display math mode. You should use

```
For every $a \in (0,1)$, ...
```

You can also use

```
For every \(a \in (0,1)\), ...
```